# CRUD and Retrieval Issues

Tags: .net-core, crud

I am developing a Web API.  So far, I have successfully gotten the CRUD operations to execute using .NET Core with EF 1.1.  However, when I update a record and then retrieve it, I keep getting the old version of the record not the currently updated one.  On the database table, the updated record is correct, but the retrieved version of it using the Web API is incorrect.

When I stop the  Web Service and start it, I get the correct version. How can I always get the most real-time correct version of a record using the Web API?  The Web API is to be used by a banking payment system where real-time up-to-date information is critical.

Comment: I don't know this technology, but do you have a model definition, or ORM settings? If so, readers will probably need to see them. How do you do the retrieval? Please add any relevant configuration or code into your question.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: When you get it back from the db during debug it is the old version
 (before you return it)? In which case there is maybe ORM caching. Or are you using the CreatedAtAction incorrectly?